# SSH command can not start remote java process

Tags: java, ssh

I have a `start` function, and I put it in a script resides on a remote site, the function's code shows below.

```
function start() {
    cd $install_dir

    mkdir -p logs

    export classpath=$classpath:$target_jar
    nohup java -Xms2048m -Xmx8192m -server -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m \
        -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \
        -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow \
        -cp $target_jar $main_class >> logs/jvm.log 2>&1 &

    echo "Service started, see logs"
}
```

And when I try to call that function use ssh `ssh xxx@host "./service.sh start"`, I can not start the java process, I only got the response message "Service started, see logs" and there's no error, the jvm.log is also empty. It apparently to me that my script has executed, but the target java process didn't run.

If I logon to that remote site, and execute `./service.sh start`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were able to run the service manually, the ssh and script part is fine.

What could go wrong is the environment. For example you referred java without absolute path. Hence your may be running a different version of it.  It is also possible that variable for shared library loading (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) are having different values.

Finally check for file permissins